# ES6 function destructuring assignment as a object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, this is a function accept a param what typeof `Object`, just like

```
function(object) {}
```

In ES6+, we can write like

```
function({ key }) {}
```

And now I want use the object, just like

```
function(object:{ key }) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(object)
}
```

Comment: please add an example of the object and the wanted output.

Comment: `function(object) { const {key} = object; console.log(object, key) }`?

Comment: in `ES6` you can use `destructuring` because you can and you need, not because you must. If you need the whole parameter itself, just dont use `destructuring`

Comment: you do not need destructing in your use case when you want whole object's reference. Just because es6 offers such fancy syntactic sugar, doesn't mean you should always use it

Comment: but what is the question about?

Answer (score 2):

Once a parameter is destructured, it isn't available (except for `arguments` in regular functions). There is no such syntax as `function(object:{ key }) {...}`.

If original object is supposed to be used, it shouldn't be destructured as a parameter:

```
function(object) {
  const { key } = object;
  console.log(key);
  console.log(object)
}
```

If there's no real benefit in using `key`, desctructuring can be skipped in favour of `object.key`.